# What is the underlying technology of QT GUI Framework for Windows?

Tags: qt

What technology does QT use at its core?

Is it assembly language of Win32 API or anything else?

Comment: What does the Win32 API have to do with assembly language? What are you asking here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look into the code, which you can download under http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#qt-lib

Answer (score 1):

[GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be my guess.